# ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk - module federation (Apache Superset)

Tags: webpack, apache-superset, webpack-module-federation

entryFile in the request status 200. But during imports, error:

`entryFile.js:231 Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk src_constTest_ts failed. (missing: http://localhost:3000/static/assets/src_constTest_ts.84972c0c.chunk.js) while loading "./constants" from 1 at __webpack_require__.f.j (entryFile.js:231:29) at entryFile.js:106:40 at Array.reduce (\<anonymous\>) at __webpack_require__.e (entryFile.js:105:67) at ./constants (entryFile.js:22:30) at get (entryFile.js:29:23) at u (remotes loading:33:20) at i (remotes loading:45:62) at remotes loading:35:54 at async Promise.all (:3000/index 0)`

[This chunk file was loading but content type showing as text/html instead of application/javascript when file loads in network tab response header.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USlhR.png)

export. webpack.config. Application (apache superset)

```
const output = {
  path: BUILD_DIR,
  publicPath: `${ASSET_BASE_URL}/static/assets/`,
};

new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: 'superset',
    filename: 'entryFile.js',
    exposes: {
      './constants': './src/constTest.ts',
    },
  })
```

import. webpack.config. Application (create react app)

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "cra",
  remotes: {
     Superset: "superset@http://localhost:8088/static/assets/entryFile.js",
  },
});

module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
   output: {
      path: paths.appBuild,
      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,
      filename: isEnvProduction
        ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js"
        : isEnvDevelopment && "static/js/bundle.js",
      // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js"
        : isEnvDevelopment && "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
      assetModuleFilename: "static/media/[name].[hash][ext]",
      publicPath: "auto",
    },
}
```

import. Application (create react app). App.tsx

`import("Superset/constants").then((data) => console.log(data));`

Comment: Hi @Flegcore. Were you able to resolve it. I am also getting CHunk Error Randomly when using the Dashboard and Chart.

Comment: No. As a result, connect @superset-ui/embedded-sdk